# SSL connection required for plugin "mysql_clear_password". Check if 'sslMode' is enabled

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

While connecting to Cloudsql DB via auth proxy from java application I am getting below error.
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SSL connection required for plugin "mysql_clear_password". Check if 'sslMode' is enabled.`

Not able to get through mysql docs the correct value to be set.

Has anyone faced similar issue ?

Below is the code for reference:

```
        String jdbcURL = String.format("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/%s", DB_NAME);
        Properties connProps = new Properties();
        connProps.setProperty("user", DB_USER);
        connProps.setProperty("password", DB_PASSWORD);
        connProps.setProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CONNECTION_NAME);
        connProps.setProperty("authenticationPlugins ", "com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin");
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the Java connector directly? It provides all the benefits of the proxy, but is in-process. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below to JDBC connection string

```
?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/path/to/keystore&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=<pwd>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html), you can find how to modify MySQL accounts. You can use an `ALTER USER` statement to enable authentication, [SSL/TLS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html#alter-user-tls), resource-limit, and password-management properties for existing accounts.

**EDIT:**

Additionally, since you cannot change anything on the DB/server side, you could try to pass `sslMode="REQUIRED"` flag along with JDBC connection.

Comment: I have already followed above steps & documents :/ @Mabel A.

Comment: @mayankagarwal have you checked this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html)? Most likely, if server isn't configured to use `mysql_clear_password` as a default, the user you're trying to connect with is created using `IDENTIFIED WITH` `mysql_clear_password` clause. Please check and alter user using appropriate plugin.

Comment: Yes I saw the doc. I can not change anything on the DB/server side.
Is there a way to override the plugin settings on the client-side ?
I am trying to override the defaultAuthNPlugin as shown here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-authentication.html#cj-conn-prop_authenticationPlugins but seems not working.
@Mabel A.

Comment: @mayankagarwal have you tried to pass [sslMode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html)="REQUIRED" flag along with JDBC connection?